# c# optimizing cycle working with big numbers

Tags: c#

I have this code that finds numbers in a given range that contain only 3 and 5 and are polynoms(symetrical, 3553 for example). The problem is that the numbers are between 1 and 10^18, so there are cases in which I have to work with big numbers, and using BigInteger makes the program way too slow, so is there a way to fix this ? Here's my code:

```
namespace Lucky_numbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string startString = Console.ReadLine();
            string finishString = Console.ReadLine();
            BigInteger start = BigInteger.Parse(startString);
            BigInteger finish = BigInteger.Parse(finishString);

            int numbersFound = 0;

            for (BigInteger i = start; i <= finish; i++)
            {
                if (Lucky(i.ToString()))
                {
                    if (Polyndrome(i.ToString()))
                    {
                        numbersFound++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        static bool Lucky(string number)
        {
            if (number.Contains("1") || number.Contains("2") || number.Contains("4") || number.Contains("6") || number.Contains("7") || number.Contains("8") || number.Contains("9") || number.Contains("0"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        static bool Polyndrome(string number)
        {
            bool symetrical = true;

            int middle = number.Length / 2;
            int rightIndex = number.Length - 1;

            for (int leftIndex = 0; leftIndex <= middle; leftIndex++)
            {
                if (number[leftIndex] != number[rightIndex])
                {
                    symetrical = false;
                    break;
                }
                rightIndex--;
            }
            return symetrical;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Turns out it's not BigInteger, it's my shitty implementation.

Comment: it would be faster if you were to just generate the palindrome instead of incrementing the number by 1 every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ulong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t98873t4.aspx):

> **Size:** Unsigned 64-bit integer
>
> **Range:** `0` to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`

But I would guess that `BigInteger` is not a problem here. I think you should create algorithm for palindrome creation instead of brute-force *increment+check* solution.

***Bonus***

Here is a palyndrome generator I wrote in 5 minutes. I think it will be much faster than your approach. Could you test it and tell how much faster it is? I'm curious about that.

```
public class PalyndromeGenerator
{
    private List<string> _results;
    private bool _isGenerated;
    private int _length;
    private char[] _characters;

    private int _middle;
    private char[] _currentItem;

    public PalyndromeGenerator(int length, params char[] characters)
    {
        if (length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("length");
        if (characters == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("characters");
        if (characters.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("characters");

        _length = length;
        _characters = characters;
    }

    public List<string> Results
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_isGenerated)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return _results.ToList();
        }
    }

    public void Generate()
    {
        _middle = (int)Math.Ceiling(_length / 2.0) - 1;
        _results = new List<string>((int)Math.Pow(_characters.Length, _middle + 1));
        _currentItem = new char[_length];

        GeneratePosition(0);

        _isGenerated = true;
    }

    private void GeneratePosition(int position)
    {
        if(position == _middle)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _characters.Length; i++)
            {
                _currentItem[position] = _characters[i];
                _currentItem[_length - position - 1] = _characters[i];
                _results.Add(new string(_currentItem));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < _characters.Length; i++)
            {
                _currentItem[position] = _characters[i];
                _currentItem[_length - position - 1] = _characters[i];
                GeneratePosition(position + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var generator = new PalyndromeGenerator(6, '3', '5');
generator.Generate();
var items = generator.Results.Select(x => ulong.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Strange riddle, but can be simplified if I understand the requirement.
I would first map these numbers to binary as there is only two possible
"lucky" digits, then generate the numbers by counting in binary until
I have completed nine bits. Reflect it for the full number, then
convert 0 to 3 and 1 to 5.

Example 1101
 Reflect it = 10111101 --> 53555535

Do this from 0 all the way to 111111111

Answer (score 2):

Declare start and finish to be static inside the class.

Change the method `Lucky` to:

```
static bool Lucky(string number)
{
    return !(number.Contains("1") || number.Contains("2") || number.Contains("4") || number.Contains("6") || number.Contains("7") || number.Contains("8") || number.Contains("9") || number.Contains("0"));
}
```

Also, you can use Parallel library to parallelize the computation.
Instead of using a regular for loop, you could use a `Parallel.For`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the problem a different way - how many *strings* of up to 9 *characters* (using only `'3'` and `'5'`) can you make?  for each string you have 2 palindromes (one repeating the last character, one not) that you can make.

e.g.

```
3 -> 33
5 ->, 55
33 -> 333, 3333
35 -> 353, 3553
53 -> 535, 5335
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion I have is to use a 3rd party library like [intx](http://intx.codeplex.com/), or some unmanaged code. The intx author reports that it can work faster than BigInteger in some situations: "System.Numerics.BigInteger class was introduced in .NET 4.0 so I was interested in performance of this solution. I did some tests (grab test code from GitHub) and it appears that BigInteger has performance in general comparable with IntX on standard operations but starts losing when FHT comes into play (when multiplying really big integers, for example)."

Comment: There is no single multiplication is his `BigInteger` usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number has to be symmetrical, you only need to check the first half of the number. You don't need to check 18 digits, you only have to check to 9 digits and then swap the order of the characters and add them to the back as a string.

Comment: Got an example handy?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is if you are *only* going to count integers that are containing 3 or 5 you don't need to traverse the *entire* list of numbers between your beginning & ending range.

Instead, look at your character set as either '3' or '5'. Then you can simply go through the allowed permutations of *half* of the number itself, leaving the other half to be completed to successfully create a polyndrome.

There are some rules to this method which would help, such as :

- if the starting number's left-most digit was greater than 5 there is no need to attempt for that specific number of digits.
- if both numbers fall on the same amount of digits but left-most digits do not traverse / include 5 or 3, no need to process.

Developing some set of rules such as this may help other than attempting to check *every* possible permutation.

So, for example, your *Lucky* function would become something more along the lines of :

```
    static bool Lucky(string number)
    {
        if((number[0] != '3') && (number[0] != '5'))
        {
            return false;
        }                  //and you could continue this for the entire string
        ...
    }
```